# Drupal Mail Programmatically - Tutorial Needed

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

All!

As the title says, I am new to deal with Drupal and I need to make a module that sends emails whose content is based on HTML and preferably using Twig templates. At the same time, these messages are sent by triggering them through restful web services.

I know how to create a custom module, but I have not dealt with Twig templates and I do not know how to read them in the code and how I can inject data into their placeholders.

I have read about some ways to send e-mails programmatically through Drupal and I did not understand well. An example of this is the use of the `hook_mail()`. What I understood is that I have to make a custom module and then use this function with the word hook replaced with the name of the module and then make a function that uses the mail manager in Drupal `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')`, but what I don't understand is where to put that `hook_mail()` function inside the custom module?!!! Is it in a PHP file inside The src folder and where is inside the src folder?!!!. What I know is that if I make a special Form that I have to put its PHP file inside the Forms folder, which is inside the src folder. So where do I put it? Is the mail manager, `\Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail')`, inside Drupal built internally or is it an external plug-in that has to be installed? Does it support HTML messages?

Best Regards,
Amr Rashad

Comment: HOOK_mail would go in your custom module `.module` file. You register your twig themes with [HOOK_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme/9.2.x). You create variables for your twig via a render array and tell it to use your twig file via the `#theme` array key. Take a look at the [Theme system overview](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/themeable/) page. This question is very broad, ie. basically asking for a tutorial, and will probably be closed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying some information and answering others. I hope this topic is not closed. And I hope those who have an answer, preferably with a full explanation, provide it, as I searched a lot, and unfortunately, the answers were not enough. For example, you mentioned the theme. Does I have to make my own theme with Twig files or can I add it to the same custom module and how can I refer to it if it was the same module or with another module I mean how can I tell the message x that its Twig is that.